# Logging Xml using global.asax or Ihttmodule

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, httprequest, httpresponse

In a web service i need to log every single request coming and those request are in xml form.
problem is whenever i am trying to log the data into a text file i am getting some unicode value for xml character(i guess so). Can you please help me to write correct text. As of now My XMl file looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <Fields>
    <Field>
      <DealeCode>C001</DealeCode>
      <IMEI>158518121</IMEI>
      <DealerName>Mohan Sales</DealerName>
      <UploadDate>17/10/2014</UploadDate>
    </Field>
  </Fields>

  System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
  string bodyText = reader.ReadToEnd();
  reader.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

  System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\LogFile.txt", bodyText);
```

And below is how my log file looks like after writing xml.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <HelloWorld xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xmlData>
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <Fields>
          <Field>
            <DealeCode>C001</DealeCode>    
            <IMEI>158518121</IMEI>    
            <DealerName>Mohan Sales</DealerName>    
            <UploadDate>17/10/2014</UploadDate>  
          </Field>  
        </Fields>
      </xmlData>
    </HelloWorld>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

However when i am trying to save my log file using XDocument it says illegal characters. Please help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well my log file output has been changed by the reviewer it seems which he shouldnt do if website already asks this when posting the file, i intentionally did that unformated xml because that was my actual result.

To make this clear I am getting below characters
&lt ;
&gt ;
&XlgD ; etc..

Comment: I have sorted this out.